# Connecting Point Data with Lines using QGIS Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I have two point datasets; `Person` (in red) and `Connections` (in blue).
They have matching columns `Person_UID`.
I'm trying to connect the red points to all the blue points that have matching Person_UIDs.
So far I am only able to make one connection for each UID in'Connections' the point that was first digitized.

Code:
`make_line( $geometry, geometry(get_feature('Connections', 'Person_UID', "Person_UID")) )`

I'm using QGIS 3.12.0

Screen grab attached.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression is correct but you are using the wrong layer.

To create a group of lines that connects all the Person points with the Connections points you need to change the order of the layers.

Instead using Person Layer, create a line with Geometry generator in the Connections layer with the expression

```
make_line( $geometry, geometry(get_feature('Person', 'Person_UID', "Person_UID")) )
```

It will create the line that you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add another answer in case anyone has a similar situation but wants to use the Person layer for some reason or wants a many-to-many join.

You need to use `aggregate()` - which returns multiple matches from one point returned as a multigeometry (one to many join), instead of `get_feature()` which will only ever return one feature each time (one to one or many to one join).

However, the expression that I got to work was a lot more complex than I thought. You can't use `make_line()` to join a single point (from the Persons layer) to multipoints (matching points in Connections layer). So you have to convert the Connections multipoints to an array of single points and then make a line from each Person point to it. I did this using `generate_series()` to create an array of number of points and looped through the multipoints using that and `array_foreach()`.

`collect_geometries(array_foreach(
                   generate_series(1,num_geometries(
                                   aggregate('connections','collect',$geometry,
                                             "Person_UID"=attribute(@parent,'Person_UID')))),
                   make_line($geometry,geometry_n(
                                       aggregate('connections','collect',$geometry,
                                                 "Person_UID"=attribute(@parent,'Person_UID'))
                                       ,@element))))`

[image]

The bonus is that this works for many-to-many joins as well, where `get_feature()` won't work no matter which layer you use it on.

[image]

EDIT: The above works if your Persons layer is a Point geometry (not Multipoint).
Your Connections layer can be a Point or Multipoint geometry.

If your Persons layer is a Multipoint geometry then `make_line()` using `$geometry` won't work - you need to convert your Persons layer to single point either by creating a new layer, or using this even lengthier expression to loop through the multipoint geometries in each Person feature.

Would be nice to have a "promote to single parts" expression in the QGIS expression builder...

`collect_geometries(array_foreach(generate_series(1,num_geometries(aggregate('connections','collect',$geometry,"Person_UID"=attribute(@parent,'Person_UID')))),make_line(array_foreach(generate_series(1,num_geometries($geometry)),geometry_n($geometry,@element)),geometry_n(aggregate('connections','collect',$geometry,"Person_UID"=attribute(@parent,'Person_UID')),@element))))`