# Display connections between points in QGIS interactively

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a layer (**pointLayer**) with point features:
Fields: **ID**, **toID**.

All points have a value in **ID**, some have a value in **toID**.
If a point "A" has a value in **toID**, I want to display a line between point "A" and the point with the **ID** = point "A"'s **toID**.
The line doesn't have to be stored permanently, but it would be good if it **automatically** appeared/disappeared upon a change of **toID** value.

How can I best achieve that?

My approach so far has been:

1. Creating a new GPKG layer of geometry type = Lines (**lineLayer**) and
   adding one field: **fromID**.
2. Copying all points, changing the wkt from "PointZ" to "LineStringZ",
   giving them some fake geometry and pasting them to the **lineLayer**.
3. Then updating the geometry like:

```
geom_from_wkt('LineStringZ(' ||
x(geometry(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',fromID))) || ' ' ||
y(geometry(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',fromID))) || ' ' ||
z(geometry(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',fromID))) || ', ' ||
x(geometry(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',attribute(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',fromID),'toID')))) || ' ' ||
y(geometry(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',attribute(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',fromID),'toID')))) || ' ' ||
z(geometry(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',attribute(get_feature('pointLayer','ID',fromID),'toID')))) ||
')'
)
```

But that means if I change something in the **pointLayer**, I have to update the geometry of the **lineLayer** to see the changes.

Looks like I can achieve similar result using [PointConnector](https://github.com/peterahlstrom/PointConnector/), but that involves generating/updating the "from - to" table and the input layer each time (because the first field must be "the joining attribute found in the from-to list").

Another idea I got was to somehow use a virtual layer for this, i.e.:

```
SELECT "ID", "toID", geometry
FROM pointLayer
WHERE "toID" <> ''
....
and somehow update, or create the geometry.
```

But my SQL knowledge is minimal.

Comment: This answers probably can solve your problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354384/qgis-geometry-generator-connect-point-data-with-lines/354389#354389

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the keywords here were "Geometry generator" and "make_line". Thanks **Val P**, for leading me to those :). I solved this by simply specifying "Geometry generator" as the "Symbol layer type" and an expression:

```
make_line($geometry,geometry(get_feature(@layer,'ID', toID)))
```